# Access.log to std.out in JBoss EAP 6

Tags: jboss, redhat, jboss6.x

I am trying to write the output of the access.log to standard out in EAP 6.4. I've seen an article to do this in EAP 7 where the web subsystem is replaced by Undertow. Is there a way to modify the syntax under the subsystem in the standalone.xml so that this can be redirected to standard.out?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box. You're right, in EAP 7 / Wildfly it is possible.

But with little development environment, it should also be possible with EAP 6.x. All you need to do is to either extend the class org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve in the deployed application, modify its behavior to log to a JUL logger and define it as a valve in jboss-web.xml or you can create a JBoss module out of it and add this behavior from outside the app using the module in standalone.xml.